# Proper async way of waiting for a running container

Tags: python, docker, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using `python docker SDK` inside of the `aiohttp` based application. My goal is to start a container when a request comes, wait until it finish all work and return a response. I want to handle many of such requests at the same time.

I run container in the detached mode so the problem isn't in starting container itself. The problem is how to define when the container finished the work. `Container` instance of the `docker` package has a method `wait()` but it is blocking so I can't use it "just like that". So I came up with something else: I start a container, create new asyncio task and (in that task) I'm checking whether container changed its state. It looks more or less like that:

```py
import docker
import asyncio
import time

def wait_for_finish(event, container):
    try:
        container.reload()
        timeout = time.time() + 600
        while time.time() < timeout:
            if container.status == 'running' or container.status == 'created':
                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                try:
                    container.reload()
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                    break
            else:
                break
    finally:
        event.set()

docker_client = docker.from_env()
container = docker_client.containers.run(**kwargs)
event = asyncio.Event()
asyncio.create_task(
            wait_for_finish(event, container)
        )
await event.wait()
event.clear()
```

It is simple but it works fine. But my question is: **is such "dummy" way of waiting for the finish of the container (status different than `running` or `created`) is a good method?** To be honest I don't like this solution, because of few reasons and I think something is wrong with such "waiting" but I don't know what exacly...

I'm aware of the solutions such as [aiodocker](https://aiodocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) or the way with [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)/threading or even replacing `docker sdk` with `subprocess` but for now I would like to use - if it is possible - combination of `asyncio` and `docker sdk` without for example thereading

---

**EDIT**

I ended up with such solution: I make async request via `aiohttp` directly to Docker API which allows me to use mentioned `wait()` method asynchronously:

```py
await docker_socket_session.post(f'http://localhost/containers/{container_id}/wait', timeout=timeout)
```

It works fine, at least for now I don't see any meaningful drawbacks.
Thanks for help

Comment: what is the point of using `asyncio` here if the application blocks on this docker logic?

Comment: @gold_cy , provided example does not block in the meaning of disabling whole application for a meaningful time. `container.reload()` blocks beacuse it makes sync request to docker api but I think I could just replace this line with an async request directly to docker api, to check the current state of the container. My question is - ** is such approach as explicit checks of the current state of the container  in a loop is a good solution in terms of efficiency of the application? **

Answer (score 3):

There are two existing functions you can chain together to avoid the polling loop and generally simplify this code.

The docker-py `Container` object has a [`wait` method](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.wait) which blocks until the container stops, then returns.  This would replace the polling loop, and not return until the container has exited; but, it's a blocking call.

[`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) takes a function, runs it in a separate thread, and returns an awaitable that will be triggered when the function completes.  That will let you bridge a blocking I/O function into asyncio, without actually blocking the main execution.  (The documentation notes this is new in Python 3.9.)

You should be able to combine these together:

```py
import docker
import asyncio

docker_client = docker.from_env()
container = docker_client.containers.run(**kwargs)
awaitable = asyncio.to_thread(container.wait)
result = await awaitable
```

(Remember that a container can specify its own user ID and mount arbitrary host content; if the container runs as root and mounts the host `/` directory, this approach can potentially root the whole system.  Consider using a message queue like RabbitMQ or a framework like Celery to schedule jobs, without adding a Docker dependency, limiting concurrency, adding some resiliency if the jobs fail, and without the potential to take over the host.)

Comment: Your proposition is quite interesting but unfortunately - at least for now - I have to stick to python3.7 so I can't use it. And of course I'm aware of some kind of the dangers that dockers brings but anyway thank you for your note - the safier is software in the "real world" the safier is the whole internet community :) Nevertheless your response doesn't answer my question - **is such approach with polling loop to check the current state of the container is a good solution in terms of efficiency of the application?** Or I should definitely use something else?